# How to extract sequence ddl in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, extract, ddl

I have a problem when try extract ddl for sequence using this function in this query:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('SEQUENCE', base_object_name) from dual;
```

base_object_name -  name of trigger, that use sequences.
Result: **ora-31604 invalid name parameter NAME "BASE_OBJECT_NAME" for OBJECT_TYPE 'SEQUENCE'**

For example when I execute this query:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_dependent_ddl('INDEX', base_table_name) from dual;
```

in result I have indexes for specified table.

Please, help, how to extract sequence ddl using `get_dependent_ddl()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sequences are not dependent on tables, therefore you need to use `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE', 'SEQ_NAME') from dual;` to retrieve its ddl.

Comment: That does not display any result. I do have sequences and to make sure the command is working, I tried with incorrect sequence name and the above command displays that sequence was not found. But with correct name, I do not see any result. Please help.

Comment: @lupchiazoem Perhaps your sequences are in a different schema? The `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function also accepts a `schema` parameter which defaults to the caller's schema.

Comment: Could be, will check and let know. ▲

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is not dependent on a trigger. It is a separate object that requires no other object in order to exist. Use the [GET_DDL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1019414) subprogram on DBMS_METADATA instead:

```
select dbms_meta_data.get_ddl('SEQUENCE',sequence_name) from dual
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about `get_ddl()` function